# How use C++ signal to QML with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals, qml, slot

I have a program with a general manager which launch a qml interface.

This is my constructor:

```
this->m_viewer = ShapedWindows::getInstance();
this->m_comManager = new CComManager(0x80);
this->m_convert = new CDataConverter();
this->m_configGenerator = new ConfigurationGenerator();
this->m_workedThread = new QThread();
```

The creation of my UI

```
m_viewer->setColor("background:transparent");   //remove background
m_viewer->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("tr", &m_tr);
m_viewer->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("configGene", m_configGenerator);
m_viewer->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("generalManager", this);
m_viewer->setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/MyApp/HomePage.qml"));
m_viewer->setFlags (Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint);

m_viewer->setIcon(QIcon("qml/MyApp/images/Logo.bmp"));
m_viewer->setTitle("MyApp");

m_viewer->showExpanded();

m_tr.setLanguage("en");

m_configGenerator->initialise();

this->m_comManager->moveToThread(this->m_workedThread);
this->m_convert->moveToThread(this->m_workedThread);
this->m_configGenerator->moveToThread(this->m_workedThread);
this->moveToThread(this->m_workedThread);
this->m_workedThread->start();
```

When we click on a button I send this:

```
emit this->currentActionChanged("Connexion en cours ...");
if(this->m_comManager->StartCom(937500, 3, 0x81, 3, 0xC1)){
emit this->connexionStateChanged(true);
emit this->currentActionChanged("Connexion réussie");
vector<char> memoryAdd;
memoryAdd.push_back(0x00);
memoryAdd.push_back(0x00);
memoryAdd.push_back(0xA0);
QByteArray dataRead;
emit this->currentActionChanged("Lecture de la carte en cours ...");
this->m_comManager->RMBA(7, 0x23, 3, 0x63, memoryAdd, 12, dataRead);
emit this->currentActionChanged("Lecture de la carte terminée");
if(0 < dataRead.size()){
vector<string> config = this->m_convert->ConvertToString(dataRead);
this->m_configGenerator->setConfig(config);
}
Sleep(1000);
emit this->connexionStateChanged(!this->m_comManager->StopCom(3, 0x82, 3, 0xC2));
emit this->currentActionChanged("Déconnexion réussie");
}
```

Then I set my generalManager in a new thread. Other objects are set to this new thread but not my IHM class.

The problem is when I emit a signal from a class which are in my second thread, as a generalManager signal, my application crash.

Qt note this issue ASSERT: "engine->jsStackTop >= mark" in file ....\include\QtQml\5.2.0\QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4scopedvalue_p.h, line 74

Comment: What is an IHM class? Which Qt version is this? Which platform, etc? Also, show more code.

Comment: My IHM class is my proper class which inherit from QtQuick2ApplicationViewer just to define some mouse event.
I'm on QT 5.2, for windows platform.

Comment: OK, I think it is time to point out that an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would be the most helpful, at least for me. This is too much unrelated code without any functions, just statements thrown around, etc.